# Small bug in my short C code. Why?

Tags: c, floating-point, cs50

I can't figure out why this works for 90% of the inputs, but not the others.  It is meant to tell you how many coins you would get back in change.  Most test amounts work fine, but if you enter 4.20 (or $4.20), it returns 23 coins... it should be 18 coins (16 quarters and 2 nickels).  Where is the bug?  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void){

    float change = 0.00;

    printf("How much change is owed? ");
    change = GetFloat();

    float quarters = change/.25;
    change-= (int)quarters*.25;

    float dimes = change/.10;
    change-= (int)dimes*.10;

    float nickels = change/.05;
    change-= (int)nickels*.05;

    float pennies = (change+.005)/.01;
    change-=(int)pennies*.01;

    int total = (int)quarters+(int)dimes+(int)nickels+(int)pennies;

    printf("%d\n", total);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should never use floating point numbers to represent money in the first place.

Comment: Since everything is a multiple of 1 cent, why not store everything as an integer number of cents?  You'll avoid all floating-point-related hassle that way.

Comment: This is a homework assignment that is supposed to teach the float functions, thats the only reason it's written the way it is.  It's just odd that most input works fine, only certain numbers do not.  I can't rewrite it using different classes or anything, becuase this is the way the professor wants to see it.

Comment: everything isn't a multiple of 1 cent

Comment: @kallikak Name a monetary value in the question that isn't ...?

Comment: I was responding to the comment that asserted "everything is a multiple of 1 cent".  I'm old enough to remember half-cent lollies at the corner store, and, for a more meaningful example, low value stocks trade for sub-cent units.  Handling prices correctly involves careful consideration of issues of float vs integer types, and though perhaps beyond the scope the question, I don't think keeping the concern in mind is beyond the scope of the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw out the floating-point calculations. this is all based on hundredths at best, so just use integer division/modulo. **Never** rely on perfect accuracy in floating point numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void){

    float fchange = 0.00;
    int change = 0;

    printf("How much change is owed? ");
    fchange = GetFloat();

    change = (int)roundf(fchange*100.0);

    int quarters = change/25;
    change = change % 25;

    int dimes = change/10;
    change = change % 10;

    int nickels = change/5;
    change = change % 5;

    printf("%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies\n", quarters, dimes, nickels, change);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `change = (int)(fchange * 100.0);` <- you need rounding there, truncating leads to wrong results for some inputs (e.g. 4.20).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks Daniel. I totally was answering a different question when I posted this without finishing it (phat fingers).

Comment: Multitasking? I wish I could do that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Been forever since I worked with floats. You wanna check that for me? thx.

Comment: The `floor` is wrong. You could `floor` after the multiplication with 100, but there's no need if all inputs are nonnegative (if negative inputs are possible, something like `floor` would be necessary). I'd use `change = (int)roundf(fchange*100);` though.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks again. I never knew roundf() was even in the C99 std. learn something new.

Answer (score 6):

The closest `float` value to `4.20` is slightly smaller than that (4.19999980926513671875, for the usual 32-bit IEEE754 `float`s). So after you subtracted the $4 from the 16 quarters, you have an amount left that is slightly smaller than 0.2. Dividing that by 0.1 results in a value slightly smaller than 2, so your `nickels` value is 1. The same happens then after you subtract your nickel, the value is slightly smaller than 0.1, dividing by 0.05 results in a quotient slightly smaller than 2.

You should use integers only for such a computation, calculating in cents.

Comment: In Objective-C the `NSDecimalNumber` class is also an option but it'd be a lot more hassle.

Comment: +1 for the exact IEEE value.  Did you calculate that by hand or from a website?

Comment: I let my Haskell interpreter calculate that, `fromRational` converts a rational number to the closest representable floating point number.

Comment: Remind me to get one of those (the calculator). And my friends call *me* a nerd.. =P

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have it mostly covered: you should be working with fixed point here, not floating point. Be careful to round properly when going from the floating point input to your fixed point representation, though. Here is a short version I hacked up, which should work for all positive inputs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    float change = atof(argv[1]);
    int work = (int)(100*change+0.5);
    int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    quarters = work/25; work %= 25;
    dimes    = work/10; work %= 10;
    nickels  = work/5;  work %=  5;
    pennies  = work;
    printf("%.2f dollars = %d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels and %d pennies: %d coins total\n",
    change, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, quarters+dimes+nickels+pennies);
    return 0;
 }
```

For example:

```
./change 4.20
4.20 dollars = 16 quarters, 2 dimes, 0 nickels and 0 pennies: 18 coins total
```