# What's wrong with my code (CS50 2012 Pset 1 greedy)

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to make a program that gives the least amount of coins for change but if I give a number other than something that divides into quarters, it fails miserably. For example, if I input 1.25, I get 5 quarters but if I input 1.26, I get 5 quarters 1 nickel which is of course incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

void calculate_change(change_requested){   
        int num_quarters = 0;
        int num_dimes = 0;
        int num_nickles = 0;
        int num_pennies = 0;

        int val_quarters = 25;
        int val_dimes = 10;
        int val_nickles = 5;

        num_quarters = floor(change_requested/val_quarters);
        if(change_requested % val_quarters != 0){
            num_dimes = floor( (change_requested - (num_quarters * val_quarters))/val_dimes );
            if( change_requested - (((num_quarters * val_quarters) + (num_dimes * val_dimes))) != 0){
                num_nickles = floor( change_requested - ( (num_quarters * val_quarters) + (num_dimes * val_dimes)/val_nickles ));
                if( change_requested - (((num_quarters * val_quarters) + (num_dimes * val_dimes) + (num_nickles * val_nickles))) != 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i<change_requested - (((num_quarters * val_quarters) + (num_dimes * val_dimes) + (num_nickles * val_nickles))); i++){
                        num_pennies++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(num_quarters > 0){
            printf("%i Quarters ",num_quarters);
        }
        if(num_dimes > 0){
            printf("%i Dimes ",num_dimes);
        }
        if(num_nickles > 0){
            printf("%i Nickles",num_nickles);
        }
        if(num_pennies > 0){
            printf("%i Pennies",num_pennies);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

int main (void){
    printf("How Much Change Do You Need?\nAmount: ");
    float change_requested = GetFloat();
    calculate_change(change_requested * 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of change_requested? float, double, or something else?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128584/small-bug-in-my-short-c-code-why?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Please learn to use your compiler warning flags, and make sure you turn them on and heed them. They're there to protect you. You should absolutely not be writing code such as `void calculate_change(change_requested){ ... }`. This uses the 'implicit `int`' rule to declare `change_requested` as a variable of type `int`. Since there isn't a prototype for `calculate_change()` in scope (the function definition doesn't provide a prototype), the argument is passed as a `double`. All hell should break loose from there. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ Somewhat to my surprise, testing with `gcc` on Mac OS X, the argument type mismatch was not recognized by the compiler and the correct type conversion was made, so that the `float` expression was converted to an `int` argument despite there not being a prototype in scope.  I had to resort to separate compilation of the `count_change()` function to get the behaviour I expected from past (bitter) experience.  Compilers change.  You should still not use the implicit `int` declaration of the argument.

Comment: Just for good measure, the most current version of the C language has dropped 'implicit int' support altogether. _Really_ don't do it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel you are overcomplicating this. If you need to write

```
for(int i = 0; i<change_requested - (((num_quarters * val_quarters) + (num_dimes * val_dimes) + (num_nickles * val_nickles))); i++){
```

and all this in one line, then something is certainly wrong. You can do this in a much simpler way, by subtracting the value of the coins just calculated from the total amount in order to to obtain the rest:

```
int vals[] = { 25, 10, 5 };
const char *names[] = { "quarters", "dimes", "nickles" };

int pennies = 100 * GetFloat(); // not good at all, btw (*)

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int n = pennies / vals[i];

    if (n) {
        printf("%d %s ", n, names[i]);
    }

    pennies -= n * vals[i];
}

if (pennies)
    printf("%d pennies", pennies);

printf("\n");
```

As to why `GetFloat()` is not good: floating-point numbers aren't exact, so, for example, 1.26 may be actually represented as something like 1.25999946. When you convert this to an integral value, you may lose a penny or so due to truncation if you are unlucky.

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are off in your code. Take a look at this line:

`num_nickles = floor( change_requested - ( (num_quarters * val_quarters) + (num_dimes *      val_dimes)/val_nickles ));`


Your code is first going to evaluate `(num_quarters * val_quarters)` which comes out to `125`. Then it evaluates `(num_dimes * val_dimes)` which comes out to `0`. Then it divides `(num_dimes * val_dimes)` by `val_nickles` which also comes out to `0` and then adds that `0` to `(num_quarters * val_quarters)`. Thus what that line of code essentially works out to is: 
`num_nickles = floor( 126 - 125 + 0)` which turns out to be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // four kinds of coins as constant variables
    const int quarter = 25, dime = 10, nickel = 5;
    float change;
    unsigned int changeCoin, count, reminder;

    do
    {
        printf ("O hai! How much change is owned?\n");
        change = GetFloat();
    }
    while (change < 0);

    // convert input into cents
    changeCoin = round (change * 100);

    // count the coins
    count = changeCoin / quarter;
    reminder = changeCoin % quarter;

    count += reminder / dime; 
    reminder %= dime;

    count += reminder / nickel;
    reminder %= nickel;

    count += reminder;

    printf ("%d\n", count);         
}
```